# Subspaces of vector space and their spans

Tags: linear-algebra

$\def\sp{\operatorname{sp}}$
Given 2 subspaces of V, and $T\subseteq \sp(K)$
  and $K\subseteq \sp(T)$
  then $\sp(K)=\sp(T)$?

If $ T\subseteq \sp(T)\subseteq \sp(K)$
  and $K\subseteq \sp(K)\subseteq \sp(T)$
  then it is true. But in general this statement is wrong.

But I think I am missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: Subspaces of V. @Zilliput

Comment: Ah, ok.  Then, by the definition of subspace, the span of a subspace is just that subspace.

Comment: $T$ and $K$ are diffrent subspaces. Does it mean that #sp(K)=sp(T)$?

Comment: If $T$ and $K$ are subspaces and $\sp$ is span, then $\sp(T) = T$ and $\sp(K) = K$. The hypotheses $T \subseteq \sp(K)$ and $K \subseteq \sp(T)$ are therefore equivalent to $\sp(T) \subseteq \sp(K)$ and $\sp(K) \subseteq \sp(T)$; it follows immediately that $\sp(K)= \sp(T)$. A more interesting question is whether $T \subseteq \operatorname{K}$ and $K \subseteq \sp(T)$ imply $\sp(K) = \sp(T)$ in the case where $T$ and $K$ are just sets of vectors.